# Service is not accessible using netTcpBinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

This is the configuration file while hosting the service, here i hosted service using ip 127.0.0.1:36345, here service is not accessible using netTcpBinding
when i hosted the using the exact ip of server (192.168.1.47:36345) it works..

what could be possible reason and solution?

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport" name="WCFSvc.WCFService">
        <endpoint binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsDualHttp"
           contract="WCFSvc.IWCFService" />
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp"
           contract="WCFSvc.IWCFService" />
        <endpoint binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="WCFSvc.IWCFService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1:26345/WCFSvc" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:36345/WCFSvc" />
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/DataService/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
</services>
```

Comment: how are you hosting your service?? In IIS 7 ?? Do you have your own hosting app ??

Comment: i am hosting in managed windows service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be several things, here are a few that you could try:

- Is there any local firewall on the machine blocking the request?
- Is there a confilct with the net.pipe configuration?
- Is there something in the binding configuration that could be causing the problem?

What error are you getting? Is there any error being written to the eventlog?